# Why is $R-\lambda$ invertible for $|\lambda|<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I got the following question:

Why is $R-\lambda$ invertible for $|\lambda|>1$ and not invertible for $|\lambda|\leq1$ ?

R is the right shift operator on $\mathfrak{l^2}$

Answer (score 2):

If $|\lambda|>1$, prove that the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{R}{\lambda}\right)^n
$$
converges and is the inverse of $(1-R/\lambda)$, which proves that $(R-\lambda)$ is invertible.

For $|\lambda| \leq 1$, you can prove that $e_1 = (1,0,0,\ldots)$ is not in the range of $(R-\lambda)$ [break it into cases where $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda\neq 0$]

Comment: Hello. If I want to see that $e_1$ is not in range of $(R-\lambda)$ for $|\lambda|\leq 1$, then I have to see that there does not exist an element in $\ell^2$ such that $(-\lambda a_1,a_1-\lambda a_2, a_2-\lambda a_3,..)=(1,0,0,0,...)$, so the sequence fulfills $a_n=-\frac{1}{\lambda^n}$. But what now?

Comment: Does that series belong to $\ell^2$?

Comment: It does belong to $\ell^2$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^2^n}$. But this is convergent (geometric series), hence its in $\ell^2$. Where is my mistake then? I am confused.

Comment: Ofc only if $|\lambda|<1$

Answer (score 1):

Use that $R^\ast = L$ where $L$ is the left shift operator and $\|L\|=1$ and $\sigma(L)=\overline{B(0,1)}$ and $\sigma(T^\ast)=\overline{\sigma(T)}$ for any $T$. Here $\sigma$ denotes the spectrum, that is, complex $\lambda$ for which $T-\lambda$ is not invertible.

Comment: We did not show that $\sigma(L)=\overline{B(0,1)}$. Can you explain me why this is true?

Comment: @Marc Yes I can explain but I think you should try to verify this yourself. I feel that I already gave away too much information. I'll let you try and if you can't figure it out in the next 24 hours I'll add the full calculation.

Comment: @Marc A result in functional analysis is the following. Let $T$ be a linear operator, then the values of $\lambda$ where $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ does not exist are contained in the ball of radius $\|T\|$, that is $|\lambda|\leq \|T\|$. Note that this does not necessarily mean that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ doesn't exist for all $\lambda$ such $|\lambda|\leq \|T\|$, in general.

Comment: @Marc Did you do it?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer No, not yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Hardy space $H^{2}(D)$ of functions $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ on the unit disk, with norm $\|f\|^{2}_{H^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2} < \infty$. An equivalent norm is
$$
      \|f\|_{H^{2}}^{2}=\lim_{r\uparrow 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^{2}d\theta.
$$
A holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disk $D$ is in $H^{2}$ iff the above supremum is finite. The functions $\{ 1,z,z^{2},z^{3},\cdots\}$ form an orthonormal basis of $H^{2}(D)$.

In this context, the right shift operator $S$ is $(Sf)(z)=zf(z)$ because $Sz^{n}=z^{n+1}$. Here it's easier to see why $(S-\lambda I)f = (z-\lambda)f(z)$ is not invertible for $\lambda\in D$ because the inverse would have to be $f(z)/(z-\lambda)$, which isn't holomorphic unless $f(\lambda)=0$. In other words, the range is of co-dimension $1$ in $H^{2}(D)$ because all functions in the range of $(S-\lambda I)$ for $\lambda\in D$ vanish at $z=\lambda$. This is true for all $|\lambda| < 1$ (i.e., $\lambda \in D$.)

The borderline case where $|\lambda|=1$ always gives $S-\lambda I$ which is not invertible because, for example, $1/(z-\lambda) \notin H^{2}(D)$. In this case the range of $S-\lambda I$ is dense, but is not everything.

For $|\lambda| > 1$, the inverse $(S-\lambda I)^{-1}f = f(z)/(z-\lambda)$ is obvious. So $\sigma(S)=\overline{D}$ is the closed unit disk.